# How to find all strings with length 5 that contain exactly one number and 4 letters

Tags: regex

I need regex to count strings with length of 5 that contain **exactly** one number (`0-9`) and 4 letters (`a-z`).

I succeed to find only letters with `^[a-z]{5}$` but I don't know can I tell it find strings that has exactly one number.

For example:

```
jlwk6    -> one number
bjkgp
5fm8s
x975t
k88q5
zl796
qm9hb    -> one number
h6gtf    -> one number
9rm9p
jwzw2    -> one number

Total: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{5}$)[a-z]*\d[a-z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j6kaxY/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5}$)` - there must be 5 chars (other than line break chars) in the string
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `\d` - a digit
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

To extend the solution to N digits, use

```
^(?=.{5}$)[a-z]*(?:\d[a-z]*){N}$
```

Here, `[a-z]*(?:\d[a-z]*){N}` will match 0+ letters and then N occurrences of a digit followed with 0+ letters.

Comment: Great, works ! Thanks for the explanation. By the way, if I want to expand it to exactly 2 numbers and 3 letters it can be easily modified ? Because I tried to add another `\d` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regex:

```
^[a-z]*\d[a-z]*?(?<=^.{5}$)
```

Demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NWV5VB/2).

- `[a-z]*` matches any number of a-z characters before a number `\d`.
- `[a-z]*?` matches any number of a-z characters afterward.
- `(?<=^.{5}$)` is a positive lookback - it assures that there are 5 characters exactly between the start and end `^.{5}$`.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl :

```
$ perl -lne '
    $count = () = /\d/g;
    $gc += $count if $count == 1;
    END{print "Total $gc"}
' file
```

### Output :

```
Total 4
```